# Ionic do action when all images and content loaded

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Creating an Ionic app but need a way to show a loading spinner until everything is 100% loaded.

I currently have in my controller:

```
$ionicLoading.show();
```

I then do an API call and will remove the ionic loader in the promise. However, images are still being loaded etc.

Is there a way I can wait until everything is 100% loaded then perform an action? And then if possible, a way to make this affect every route.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this,

```
$ionicLoading.show();

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    /* insert your code here */

    $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
         console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
    });
    $state.go("tab.dash");
});
```